# Probability of flipping heads where the coin's bias is drawn from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability of flipping a head on a coin where the coin's probability of flipping a head is drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$.

I think this question is easy, however I am getting a result that makes no sense. Please don't directly give me the answer. I can look that up in a book.

Let $H$ be the binary event that the a head is flipped. Let $Q$ be Uniform($0,1$).

**Informal attempt:** Firstly, it's easy to see that given that we know $Q=q$, the probability of flipping heads is simply $1/q$. Since the distribution of $Q$ is uniform, we just need the average value of the function $1/q$. In particular, the probability must be $\frac{1}{1-0} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{q} \, dq$, which does not converge!

**Formal attempt:** We wish to compute $P(H= \text{True})$. By the total law of probability, we have:
$$P(H=\text{True}) = \int_0^1 P(H=\text{True}\mid Q=q)f_Q(q) \, dq = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{q} (1) \,dq$$ Again, this does not converge!? What am I doing wrong? I have a strong feeling my mistake lies in the fact that I am mixing continuous and discrete distributions. That is, I am conditioning on an event that actually cannot exist, i.e. $P(Q=q)=0$.

Comment: Without looking at your calculation, how could the answer be anything other than $\frac 12$ by symmetry?

Comment: In your calculation, where does $\frac 1q$ come from?

Comment: Why are using the inverse of q? If Q is a value uniformly selected from 0 to 1, in particular q, then q itself is the probability, not the inverse.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, you are getting special case probabilities way over $1$.

Comment: @Tyberius I have no idea. This question was stupid, ugh. Thank you, apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: @Pii not a problem. It often just takes another pair of eyes to spot these small little mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are using $1/q$ when you should be using $q$ for the probability. If $q$ is what you get by drawing from $0$ to $1$, then it is already the probability and you can simply integrate over $q$ from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(H = \text{true}\mid Q =q ) = q$$

$$f_Q(q) = 1$$

Hence you are suppose to evaluate $$\int_0^1 q \,dq$$